# Spring boot web configuration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I've configured in my spring boot project (code provides most interesting part)

```
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
  // ...
  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("googleb54ababeddd1718e.html")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/googleb54ababeddd1718e.html");
    registry.addResourceHandler("google7160e5f82e26983b.html")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/google7160e5f82e26983b.html");
    registry.addResourceHandler("google06bd5e270f77943e.html")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/google06bd5e270f77943e.html");
    //...
  }
```

this configuration works fine. If you've payed your attention, some resources different, but can be grouped by mask and handler. File names: **googleb54ababeddd1718e.html**, **google7160e5f82e26983b.html**, **google06bd5e270f77943e.html**. So I've tried next part:

```
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
  // ...
  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("google.html")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/google*.html");
    //...
  }
```

and this case does not work. I believe I very close to correct solution, but I can't detect one. Can someone provide fix of this issue or explain why the approach is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

**v1** Move all `google**` files to `google` folder and remove `google` prefix.

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/google/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
}
```

**v2**

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/{google**.html}")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
}
```